# Java singleton retrieving local variable always null after setting

Tags: java, singleton

Having an issue that really freaks me out.
So we have a MainView which displays a map (MapView which is a JComponent) on it.
In the MapView class we override the paintComponent(Graphics g) to draw our custom stuff.
Works fine so far.

We also have a RouteControl singleton class that has a local variable Route in it, which we can set with setRoute and retrieve with getRoute. Now the funny part:

When the RouteControl instance is retrieved in our MapView paintComponent the Route is always null. But we have set a route in it in our MainView, and if we retrieve the route after the set its not null.

Do I miss a critical point here, like multithreading? I also have a singleton class MapControl with the get/setMap which works.

The code to project:

```
public class MainView extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private static MainView instance;

    private void comboRouteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        File _routeFile = RouteControl.getInstance().getRouteFile(comboRoute.getSelectedItem().toString());
        Route _route = RouteControl.getInstance().loadRoute(_routeFile);
        RouteControl.getInstance().setRoute(_route);
        // if we retrieve the route here it works
    }
}
```

Now the MapView:JComponent:

```
public class MapView extends JPanel {
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // this nicely works, also set in the MainView!
        if(MapControl.getInstance().getMap() != null) {
            BufferedImage mapImage = MapControl.getInstance().getMap().getMapImage();
            g.drawImage(mapImage, 0, 0, null);   

            // draw le route THIS IS ALWAYS NULL
            if(RouteControl.getInstance().getRoute() != null) {
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.fillRect(40, 40, 15, 15);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("**** route is null");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RouteControl:

```
public class RouteControl {
    private static RouteControl instance;
    private Route route;

    public static synchronized RouteControl getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new RouteControl();
        }
        return instance;
    }    

    public Route getRoute() {
        return route;
    }

    public void setRoute(Route route) {
        System.out.println("RouteControl:setRoute");
        this.route = route;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the instances returned by RouteControl.getInstance() the same object instance?

Comment: I added private int leNumber; to RouteControl, in constructor:         Random random = new Random(); leNumber = random.nextInt(); In getInstance printout the number, it's the same.

Comment: Can you put a watch on `RouteControl.route` in debugger?

Comment: Are you definitely hitting comboRouteActionPerformed? Put a breakpoint in and make sure.

Comment: BTW curious to know why you name local variables with prefix `_` but member variables (fields) without any prefix, which is the opposite of popular naming conventions

Comment: comboRouteActionPerformed is hit, absolutely. The setRoute method also, as explained below on the next answer I have set the route now manual in the mainview. After I change the combo it gets repaint, still the route stays null. Working on my coding conventions, thanx for the tip Miserable. Also looking into the debugger now.

Comment: I've uploaded the source to http://www.2shared.com/file/gZktSbRA/leproject.html, maybe this clarify some things.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a **timing problem** here. It seems like you load the route from somewhere in the `MainView` class and set it after you've loaded it. 
If the `MapView` is painted before the loading is done, the route will be `null`.

Comment: The solution to this, by the way, is to wrap your code that updates a painting component in an SwingUtilities.invokeLater() runnable.

Comment: I have set the route in the mainview, at the same place where I set the map. Now after I change the combo the route should be set right, still doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the complete code here?

Calls like the calls below would cause compile errors, so there has to be more to it.

- File _routeFile = RouteControl.getInstance().getRouteFile(comboRoute.getSelectedItem().toString());
- Route _route = RouteControl.getInstance().loadRoute(_routeFile);

My first guess with faulthy singleton wiring is classloading issues. Please check if the singleton objects are physically the same.